# What does "This profiling configuration does not apply to the selected run configuration" mean in JetBrains Rider and how do you resolve it?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider

I'm trying to run a profiling session [following the instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Profiling_Unit_Tests.html), but I'm stuck on the first step where it says to pick a profiling configuration as they are all disabled with the error message "This profiling configuration does not apply to the selected run configuration".

What does this mean? What might cause it? And how might I resolve it?

[image: Rider profiling configuration showing error message]

*Linux Mint 19, Rider 2020.1.3 installed via jetbrains toolbox, dotnet core installed via asdf-vm.*

Comment: According to support it's a known issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DTRC-23394

Answer (score 3):

It's not a real problem, just a UI bug I think.

In toolbar, the `profiling configuration` drop-down menu is also a button to run the current `Run/Debug Configuration`. If you set the `Run/Debug Configuration` to a normal `.NET Static Method` (often `Main` function), the profiling configuration button is enabled again. Click it will run the Main function and profiling it normally.

But you can't use this button to profile a unit test session.
Instead, this setting is automatically applied when you click `Profile selected unit test`:
[image]

Just select the config you want, start the unit test, it will work.

This logic is more clear in menu. In the `Run` menu, third item `Profile XXX Using YYY` has a same icon with `profiling configuration`. Hover the `profiling configuration` button will show a tooltip contains a message equals the menu item.

And you can't run a unit test in `Run` menu, there is a `Tests` menu instead.

---

One more thing: Rider profiling support in Linux is incomplete, I recommend you do profiling things in Windows.